# Why elements adding at the end of ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I am working with custom ListView.

Why items were added to the end of list view?

I have only 3 items. `15000.00` is added first (so it is not reversed).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because of your layout file. Change the `android:layout_height=wrap_content` of your ListView tag to `android:layout_height=match_parent`.

Comment: A good way of finding out what's wrong with your layouts is to use the Hierarchy Viewer tool that comes with the sdk.

Comment: Is it possible to use it in IDEA?